# How to prove the goals in more elegant way using ssreflect?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

It seems my coq proofs are longer and uglier than expected and I can't achieve ssreflect advantages in them despite my attempts. I think I missed some key points. Or maybe I just need to know more tactics.

Here are some proofs I came up with. Please, help me to find and fix bad lines or decisions I made. I noted with comments the lines that I doubt. Advice about evidence or sources of knowledge will also be useful.

```ml
(* SSReflect proof language requires these libraries to be loaded and options to be set. *)
From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.
From Coq Require Import Nat Arith Lia.

Lemma L1: forall A B C, A -> (A -> B /\ C) -> C.
Proof.
move => A B C H1 H2.
(* Seems like there is a way to apply H2 in H1 without moving them from goal. *)
apply H2 in H1. 
destruct H1 as [H3 Goal].
done.
Qed.

Lemma L2: forall A Q, (forall x, (exists y, x + y = y + x) -> A) -> Q -> A.
Proof.
move => A _ T _.
(* I think there is a better way then coming up with this "H" or smth. *)
assert (H: exists y, 2 + y = y + 2) by (exists 0; lia).
(* Again, there should be the way to do apply via ssreflect. *)
apply (T 2) in H.
done.
Qed.

Lemma divides_by_2_by_3_means_by_6 : 
        forall z p q, z = 2 * p -> z = 3 * q -> exists n, z = 6 * n. 
Proof.
move => a b c P Q.
(* Which way is better to create a subgoal? *)
assert (odd_or_even: forall n, (exists k, n = 2 * k) \/ (exists k, n = 2 * k + 1)). {
  induction n.
  - left. exists 0. lia.
  - destruct IHn as [[x H] | [x H]].
    + right; exists x; lia.
    + left; exists (x + 1); lia.
}
(* How can I add new fact in context? I found this way, but there should be the right one. *)
move : (odd_or_even c) => H.
destruct H as [[x H] | [x H]].
- exists x; lia.
- lia.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take the best out of `ssreflect`, you might also consider using the full mathematical components library.  But for now, I will just illustrate the tactics, not the theorems.  I am a frequent user of `ssreflect` and mathematical components, so this will also contain some stylistic habits that are enforced in this library (like the convention for indentation, which is  2 * (n - 1) spaces, where n is the number of open goals), and the habit of adding "by" at the beginning of every line that finishers a proof.

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.
From Coq Require Import Nat Arith Lia.

Lemma L1: forall A B C, A -> (A -> B /\ C) -> C.
Proof.
by move=> A B C /[swap] /[apply] - [].
Qed.
```

The `\[swap]` and `\[apply]` introduction patterns are fairly recent additions to the language.

```
Lemma L2: forall A Q, (forall x, (exists y, x + y = y + x) -> A) -> Q -> A.
Proof.
by move=> A _ + _ => /(_ 2); apply; exists 0; lia.
Qed.
```

In this example note the use of `+` to express that the hypothesis is kept in the goal, while the next one is discarded by `_`.

The `apply` tactic without argument takes its argument as the first proposition on the left of arrows in the goal.

```
Lemma divides_by_2_by_3_means_by_6 : 
  forall z p q, z = 2 * p -> z = 3 * q -> exists n, z = 6 * n. 
Proof.
have odd_or_even : forall n, (exists k, n = 2 * k) \/
  (exists k, n = 2 * k + 1).
  elim=> [ | n [[k kP] | [k kP]]]; first by left; exists 0.
    by right; exists k; lia.
  by left; exists (k + 1); lia.
move=> a b c P Q; move: (odd_or_even c)=> [[x H] | [x H]].
  by exists x; lia.
by lia.
Qed.
```

Here the `elim` tactic behaves like the `apply` tactic in the previous example: it takes its argument as the leftmost universally quantified (or premise) on the goal.  Introduction patterns are used directly to *destruct* the hypotheses which are disjunctions or existential statements.

Until recently, mathematical components made little use of `lia` so this is not completely idiomatic ssreflect code, but it does work.  Personnally, I am a bit confused that `lia` manages to solve the last goal.

Comment: Yves, on my version of Coq, the `move=> a b c P Q` must be replaced by `move=> P Q`.

Comment: @PierreJouvelot, you are right.  The line `move=> a b c.` at the beginning of the proof was intended to be removed.

Comment: I don't understand, I approved your edits, but they do not appear.

Comment: My edits were not related to your code, but to Markdown. Since they ended up not being effective, I removed them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible non-lia-based solution for the last goal, based on @Yves ideas:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma divides_by_2_by_3_means_by_6 : 
  forall z p q, z = 2 * p -> z = 3 * q -> exists n, z = 6 * n. 
Proof.
have odd_or_even : forall n, (exists k, n = 2 * k) \/
  (exists k, n = 2 * k + 1).
  elim=> [ | n [[k kP] | [k kP]]]; first by left; exists 0.
    by right; exists k; rewrite kP addn1.
  by left; exists (k + 1); rewrite kP -addnS mulnDr muln1.
move=> a b c P Q; move: (odd_or_even c) => [[x H] | [x H]].
  by exists x; rewrite Q H mulnA; congr (_ * _).
move: P.
rewrite Q H => /eqP.
have -> : 3 * (2 * x + 1) = 2 * (3 * x + 1) + 1.
  by rewrite 2!mulnDr !mulnA mulnC -addnA; congr (_ + _).
have -> // : forall n m, (2 * n + 1 == 2 * m) = false.
  by move=> n m; rewrite !mul2n addn1 eqn_leq leq_Sdouble ltn_double ltnNge andNb.
Qed.
```

Note that the last subgoal to be proved (`exists n : nat, a = 6 * n`) is solved by showing that the context is contradictory, which lia was able to deal with.